# fs.existsSync returns false on windows for a file, read lock file of which was manually deleted

Tags: javascript

During some read and write operations, some errors were encountered and it was noticed that there was a read lock file.

For example, if I was working on a file "/someFolder/someFile.txt", i had a read lock file by the name "/someFolder/someFile.txt_" that was left alive after some runtime error.

I manually deleted it. I manually deleted the original file and recreated the same.

But now the following always returns false and node js simply refuses to recognize the file for any kind of operation.

`console.log(fs.existsSync(somePath));`

on `fs.access(somePath)` I get the error:

```
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access 'C:\somefile.json'
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'access',
  path: 'C:\\somefile.json'
 }
```

Any workaround for this?

Comment: Please try again with a new folder and check the permissions, I've often seen problems when trying to write/read files in the c: root directory.

Comment: This is actually not root directory btu c:/x/y...

Comment: It works for all other things but not for this particular file